# CDATA xml parsing extra greater than problem

Tags: php, html, xml, tags, cdata

I am creating an xml using php and parsing that xml in iphone application code. In description field there is some html tags and text.

I am using following line to convert this html tags in to xml tag using CDATA.

```
 $response .= '<desc><![CDATA['.trim($feed['fulltext']).']]></desc>';
```

Now, here my $feed['fulltext'] value is like this

```
<span class="ABC">...text...</span>
```

In xml I am getting following response,

```
<desc><![CDATA[><span class"ABC">...text...</span>]]></desc>
```

You can see here, I am getting an extra greater-than symbol just before the value of $feed['fulltext'] starts. (like this: >...text...)

Any solution or suggestion for this?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: Aha! wondering where this comes from it is in all sorts of feeds on the web. Must be a bug! Can you give me a minimal piece of code that produces this and which version of php you are using and which libxml version if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using cdata and just xml/html encoding the value of ? That's normally my preferred way of sending html over xml.

i.e.

```
<desc>&lt;span class=&quot;ABC&quot;&gt;...text...&lt;/span&gt;</desc>
```

Sorry I can't help with the extra > as I'm more of a .net developer than php.